# Need to migrate Spanner db from one GCP Project to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, google-cloud-spanner

I am looking for a tool which is capable of migrating GCP spanner databases from one project to another. It would not be a regular migration that I am looking for, maybe once in 10 days migration would be done. Is there any tool that can help me with this? I am using `GOOGLE_STANDARD_SQL` dialect in Spanner

Comment: So you really want to periodically sync data across Spanner databases every 10 days?  Or are you looking to move all the data from one Spanner instance to another every 10 days?

Comment: anyone of these works for my use case

Comment: Will look deeper into this, but I think the only "out of the box" option available is to create a backup (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/create-backup), copy the backup to a different project (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/copy-backup#common_cross-project_use_cases) and then restore to an instance in the other project(s) (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/restore-backup)

Comment: Okay. please let me know if there is any solution to ensure all spanner db of different project are in sync please let me know. The scenario is like if I make a change in dev db which is in dev project it must also happen in qa spanner db which is in another gcp project

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate entire database, then create backup (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup), copy backup to new project and then restore it in a spanner instance in that project.
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/copy-backup

Answer (score 0):

Migrating projects with no organization resource
You can migrate a project that is not associated with an organization resource into an organization resource. However, you can't change it back to No organization using this process. If you have a project that is associated with your organization resource and you want to revert it to No organization.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you have said. Can you add some document which i could go through?

Comment: Please correct typos, repetitions and grammar before submitting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are 3 ways you could go about this. A few people pointed to Backup/Restore as an option, which is a good start, but there are two others:

1. Backup/Restore

As mentioned above, a Backup can be restored to another instance in a different region or project. The destination instance must exist prior to copying the backup over. The backup file itself is a proprietary, encrypted format and can only used to restore to a Spanner instance [1].

2. Import/Export

While similar to Backup/Restore, one feature of this approach is that the data can be exported to either CSV or avro format [2]. It is simply a file on GCS, so you have a bit more flexibility. It's also worth highlighting that the export job is run as a medium-priority task, so there may be some impact to performance.

For more information, here's a breakdown comparing the two approaches.[3]

3. Change Streams

Change streams expose CDC capabilities to Spanner users [4]. For this particular use case, you would need to configure a change stream on the `dev` database and then consume the events to replicate to the separate, `qa` instance. Like Import/Export, this gives the user flexibility to copy the data verbatim or even modify it before writing to the destination host.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/copy-backup#common_cross-project_use_cases

[2] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import-export-overview

[3] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup/choose-backup-import

[4] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/change-streams